# Multiple Input Paths in newHadoopAPI for spark to read Lzo files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am working on a Spark Application that has to read multiple directories (i.e. multiple paths) from S3 Bucket and HDFS. I read that newHadoopAPI provides a great way to read Lzo compressed / indexed files in a good performant way. But, how do we read multiple folder paths / directories have several Lzo files and Index files in an RDD using newHadoopAPI?

The folder structure is like partitioned Hive Table on two columns.
Ex: as below. Partition on date and batch

> /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=5678/001_0.lzo
>   /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=5678/001_0.lzo.index
>   /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=5678/002_0.lzo
>   /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=5678/002_0.lzo.index
>   /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=8765/001_0.lzo
>   /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=8765/001_0.lzo.index
>   /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=8765/002_0.lzo
>   /rootDirectory/date=20161002/batch=8765/002_0.lzo.index

..... and so on.

Now I use the below code to read data from S3. This treats both Lzo and Lzo.Index files as input which crashes my application, as I dont want to read .lzo.index files, but just the .lzo files using the index for speed.

```
val impInput = sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile("s3://my-bucket/myfolder/*/*", classOf[NonSplittableTextInputFormat],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text])
    val impRDD = impInput.map(_._2.toString)
```

Could anyone please help me to understand how can I do that?

1). Read all (mulitple) folders under the root for the Lzo files using the newHadoopAPI so that I can utilize the .index file for my benefit.

2). Read the data from HDFS in the similar fashion.

Comment: Try this  https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201312.mbox/%3CCA+-p3AGA6f86qcSOwP7k_r+8R-DGBmj3gz+4xLJZjpr90DbNxg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Thanks @AyanGuha - But this seems to be not working. In the example there is a big meaty file of 78 GB (.lzo) and he is using it to read that using indexes.

In my case, I have several small files and seem that i am not getting any benefit of using Lzo files due to the large number of small files. The hierarchy is as shown above.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a suffix to your HDFS path may help.

```
val impInput = sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile("s3://my-bucket/myfolder/*/*.lzo", classOf[NonSplittableTextInputFormat],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text])
```